# magit blame: how to go to the commit my cursor is currently on

Tags: magit, git

I want to checkout the file as it was when before the commit was applied so I can dig deeper.

Now I just resort to command line git to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter magit blame mode ('M-x magit-blame'), then place your cursor on a line within that commit and press 'b', then 'b' again.